# Filtering a dataframe in row names from a column values

Tags: r, filtering, dataframe

Basically I have dataframe with two columns (`target_id` and `fpkm`). I want to keep only those row names in first column that are not duplicated.
For example in the below dataframe you can see there are two row names with the same name (almost) `comp267138_c0_seq1` `comp267138_c0_seq2` and from both and I want to keep only one `comp267138_c0_seq2` based of high value in column 2.

```
       target_id        fpkm
comp247393_c0_seq1    3.197885
comp257058_c0_seq4    1.624577
comp242590_c0_seq1    1.750319
comp77911_c0_seq1     1.293059
comp241426_c0_seq1    1.626589
comp288413_c0_seq1   14.828853
comp294436_c0_seq1   11.555596
comp63603_c0_seq1     1.982386
comp267138_c0_seq1    8.594494
comp267138_c0_seq2   11.134958
comp321623_c0_seq1    6.934149
```

Comment: + 1 for posting example data.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you only want to consider part of the `target_id` (the first two components, splitting by `_`)

If your `data.frame` is called `DT`

```
# create   column without the _seqx part
DT$new_id <- sapply(lapply(strsplit(as.character(DT[['target_id']]), '_'), head, 2),
              paste, collapse = '_')
library(plyr)


ddply(DT, .(new_id), function(x) x[which.max(x$fpkm),])
```